# Javascript HTML5 Canvas draw path issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

the code below is working except it appears to be drawing the line about 100px below the mouse coordinates, sometimes when I refresh Chrome (or firefox) the issue either fixes itself or it doesn't work at all! Can anybody explain to me what the problem could be?

Thanks!

> ```
> function setXAndYOne (newX, newY) {
>     x = newX;
>     y = newY;
>   }
> ```

```
  function setXAndYTwo (newX, newY) {
    x = x2;
    y = y2;
    x2 = newX;
    y2 = newY;
  }

  function drawingMouseDown (event) {
    setXAndYOne(event.pageX - offset.left, event.pageY - offset.top);
    isMousedown = true;
  }

  function drawingMouseMove (event) {
    setXAndYTwo(event.pageX - offset.left, event.pageY - offset.top);
    if (isMousedown) draw();
  }

  function drawingMouseUp (event) {
    isMousedown = false;
  }
  var ctx = drawingContext;

  function draw () {

    ctx.strokeStyle = currentColour;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth =  5/*strokeWidth*/;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Prefetch the canvas bounding box (bounding box==the canvas position relative to the page).

```
var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var BBoffsetX=BB.left;
var BBoffsetY=BB.top;
```

Then in your mouse handlers you can get the mouse postion like this:

```
var mouseX=event.clientX-BBoffsetX;
var mouseY=event.clientY-BBoffsetY;
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! That was driving me mad. Thank you.